# rspec big decimal matcher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bigdecimal

```
-:total_cost_with_tax => #<BigDecimal:7fda9d17aaf0,'0.105225E4',18(45)>,
-:total_cost_without_tax => #<BigDecimal:7fda9d17b450,'0.972E3',9(36)>,
-:total_last_installment_amount => #<BigDecimal:7fda9d17b978,'0.8011E2',18(45)>,
-:total_monthly_installment_amount => #<BigDecimal:7fda9d17abb8,'0.8011E2',18(45)>,
-:total_tax => #<BigDecimal:7fda9d17b068,'0.8025E2',18(45)>,

+:total_cost_with_tax => #<BigDecimal:7fda9d0184c8,'0.105225E4',18(36)>,
+:total_cost_without_tax => #<BigDecimal:7fda91ff2b48,'0.972E3',9(27)>,
+:total_last_installment_amount => #<BigDecimal:7fda91fee548,'0.8011E2',18(36)>,
+:total_monthly_installment_amount => #<BigDecimal:7fda91fe72c0,'0.8011E2',18(36)>,
+:total_tax => #<BigDecimal:7fda9d00a2b0,'0.8025E2',18(36)>,
```

So, these are littered throughout some of my tests... rspec 2, rails 3. I'm comparing hashes using `.should eq()` to compare. I can't seem to get the incantation right. Seems like it's a precision thing, which seems silly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

RSpec 3 has BigDecimal eq:

```
x.should eq(y)

expect(x).to eq(y)
```

If you're comparing a BigDecimal to a Float, be aware the precision can affect the comparison.

You can use this:

```
x.should be_within(delta).of(y)

expect x.to be_within(delta).of(y)
```

If you're comparing two BigDecimal numbers that have different precisions, be aware that these numbers can show different results from `inspect` and also from `hash` depending on your platform and what version of Ruby BigDecimal you're running.

For example, this can happen:

```
BigDecimal.new("2").hash == BigDecimal.new("2.0").hash
=> false
```

Your output shows that your BigDecimal string representations are slightly different.

Here's what your strings mean:

- Part 1 is the object address.
- Part 2 is the number value represented as a string.
- Part 3 is the number of significant digits then the maximum number of significant digits.

Your output shows that your strings have different object addresses, identical number values (i.e. part 2), identical significant digits (the first number in part 3), but different numbers of maximum significant digits.

For your question, using RSpec 2 and comparing `BigDecimal` hashes, you'll solve your issue by using the rspec `be_within` matcher.

Note that Ruby `BigDecimal` numbers and `Float` numbers are both floating point numbers:

- A `BigDecimal` is a arbitrary-precision decimal floating point number.
- A `Float` is the native architecture's double-precision binary floating point number.

You can see the `BigDecimal` decimal floating-point representation by doing this:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
x=BigDecimal.new(100)
=> #<BigDecimal:7f8e62038570,'0.1E3',9(27)>
```

The significand part is '0.1' and the exponent part is 'E3'.

Note that this is for the typical Ruby MRI/KRI VM. Implementations may be different on other Ruby VMs, such as JRuby, because Java has its own bignum code.

When you compare two different types of floating-point numbers, such as BigDecimal and Float, you can get results that may seem counter-intuitive because the types use different bases (decimal vs. binary), different precisions, and different Ruby classes.

Example:

```
BigDecimal.new("1.111111111111111") === 1.111111111111111
=> true
BigDecimal.new("1.1111111111111111") === 1.1111111111111111
=> false
```

Comment: For the record: not true.  The whole point of usijng BigDecimal is that it does *not* behave like a Float; you are supposed to get the number you put in.

Comment: @Andy I added more detail to address your comment.

Comment: excellent, but the point of my comment was that you shouldn't *need* to use `be_within` to match a BegDecimal. It's not like a Float; you don't need to account for rounding error because of the way the number is stored.

Comment: @Andy You're right for the typical case, but not for the OP's case of comparing hashes, at the time he wrote it, with RSpec 2, and without knowing the platform. I've added more detail for you to see.

Answer (score 3):

With Rspec 3.x you can use for BigDecimal the `eq` matcher like you can use it for float.

```
RSpec.describe "an integer" do
  it "is equal to a float of the same value" do
    expect(5).to eq(5.0)
  end
end
```

For more information see the RSpec documentation:
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-4/docs/built-in-matchers/equality-matchers

Comment: @damoiser The question was asked when RSpec was version 2, not version 3. I'll update my answer now to show both because I agree with you.